# Why can't I grant authorization to my Spotify app?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am using the spotipy library to add songs to a playlists but I keep getting errors when trying to use the 'playlist-modify-private' scope. When trying to gain authorization, the web browser opens and I allow the app access to my spotify accoutn and then i'm immediately met with an error screen. Rerunning the app just brings me straight to the error screen. I get no error code or anything so I'm lost as to why this is happening.

```
self.scope = 'playlist-modify-private'
self.redirect_uri = 'localhost:8888/callback'
self.auth = util.prompt_for_user_token(username=self.username,
                                                scope=self.scope,
                                                client_id=self.client_id,
                                                client_secret=self.client_secret,
                                                redirect_uri=self.redirect_uri)
```

I saw a post saying that for this scope i should be using util module for auth but i've had no luck. Originally I was using the auth **SpotifyClientCredentials** object and was able to finish most of the project but I was unable to modify playlist since it doesn't take a scope. I'm at a loss if anyone can provide any input.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

First set the following environment variables on your env.

```
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID="<your_client_id>"
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET="<your_client_secret>"
SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI="http://127.0.0.1:8888/callback"
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_USERNAME="<your_username>"
```

And then run the following (I'm using `dotenv` to load the variables above) Check out the doc [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/):

```py
import os
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()  # Load your environment variables from a .env file

spotify_user = os.environ.get("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_USERNAME")
spotify_scope = "playlist-modify-private"
oauth = SpotifyOAuth(username=spotify_user, scope=spotify_scope)
user_token = oauth.get_access_token(as_dict=False)
```

That will take you to your `redirect_uri` and generate a `.cache-<your_username>` file with all the information needed (token, refresh_token, etc.)

Then you create your spotify client with:

```py
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth=user_token)
```

This will automatically get your token or get a refresh token in case it's needed so you won't have to worry about this.
And then you will be able to modify your playlist with:

```py
spotify.user_playlist_add_tracks(
    user=os.environ.get("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_USERNAME"),
    playlist_id="<your_playlist_uri>",
    tracks=["<track_uri>"])
```

Here's the doc reference for the environment variables used by the spotipy library: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.15.0/?highlight=environment%20variables#quick-start

Comment: I'm still having the same issues after making these changes. When i go to login to spotify, i just get an error page and the app asks me to enter the URL i was redirected to. I'm not so sure what to do from here since spotify doesn't give me any error indication. It just has a link back to the docs

Comment: Can you paste what's the error that shows on your browser?

Comment: It's just a white blank page page saying that there was an error and displays a link back to the docs. But no error code or anything.

Comment: I imagine that happens when you run the last line `user_token = oauth.get_access_token(as_dict=False)`, is that right? Or does that happen at some other time?